# JTable: toggle an icon when I double-click a cell

Tags: swing, jtable, double-click

I have a table column that I'm overriding the DefaultCellRenderer to display an icon.

Is there a way I could detect double-clicks on a JTable cell, so I can toggle the corresponding row value's state so that it changes the icon between two values (representing "off" and "on")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways:

1) The easier way: Attach a mouse listener to the table, listen for a double click, find the row and column by rowAtPoint/columAtPoint, chenge the value, and call fireCellChanged() in the table model.

2) The harder (but slightly better) way: Have a custom cell editor that upon editing, changes the value, and calls stopCellEditing().

You don't need to do both.

Check this out as well, which does similar but with a button:
http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/

Comment: why is #2 slightly better? I actually ended up changing to a JCheckbox (just had to use a custom cell renderer for the column, and appropriate cell editor methods, I'm using GlazedLists's AdvancedTableFormat; for some reason having a custom editor as well screwed it up)

Comment: one might be possible but plain wrong - fighting against the wind ;-) two is the only acceptable (meaning: following Swing'ish) way to go.

Comment: @Jason: yeah, what kleopatra said. 1 will work, but it's not the Swing way to do things.

Answer (score -1):

When you perform a single click, the cell rendered is replaced by the cell editor, so provide also a cell editor with same appearance than the rendered, add a mouse listener and capture the double-click and perform any desired action. When you finish invoke `stopCellEditing()`.

Comment: that's simply wrong: whether or not a user gesture represents a "start-edit" is at the decision of the cellEditor (see cellEditor.isCellEditable(EventObject). And even if editing, a renderer is not "replaced": trivially can't because it's never part of the container hierarchy but only used to .. well .. stame (aka: render) the cell content at the moment of painting a cell.